# Access Views in Android ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

Is there a way to access the `View` (spinner) that is shown in the `ActionBar` when we set `setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not by any documented and supported means.

Comment: Seems so. However, `getView` and `getDropDownView` gives sufficient control over them is practical cases. Thanks!