# ActionBar: Center text on navigation bar buttons

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

**Simple aim:**

To have default buttons in the navigation bar of my `ActionBar` with the text centre aligned. I simply want to use the default, simple way of:

```
ActionBar.Tab myTab = Actionbar.newTab()
myTab.setText("my tab's text");
```

**What's the problem**

I cannot find any simple way to do this whatsoever. You can't access the views (as `ActionBar.Tab.getCustomView()` always returns `null` due to it being the default view). There is no method that I can see in `ActionBar`, `ActionBar.Tab`, etc to get the current view, get or modify `LayoutParams` (especially `Gravity`). A visualisation of the problem is below (one line seems to work right, but double lined navigation buttoms definitely seem left aligned):
[image]

**Unideal solution**

Am I right in negatively thinking that the only way to accomplish this is to use custom views for all of my tabs, somehow guess / attempt to copy the default formatting for the tabs (as I can't find anyway to access these views) and assume / hope that the default formatting / font / style of `ActionBar.Tab`'s text does not change any time soon?

Surely there has to be a better way?

Comment: An answer was accepted confirming my negative suspicions, if anyone has any smart work arounds, a better solution would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no way you can access the `Views` in `ActionBar`. Using custom layout seems the only solution. However, doesn't Android align the text to center automatically? It apparently does so in all my applications.

Comment: I've added in a picture of the problem. You're right, the single line buttons do seem to have centre-aligned text, but as soon as it becomes double line it seems not to. Seems odd to be honest (unless I am overlooking something in the text formatting process). Either way, I still would like to change it and can't seem to do that easily

Comment: `ActionBar` doesn't have a method to access its `View`s. On the other hand, if you use custom `View`s, you'll possibly have to worry about orientation change and screen size changes.

Comment: A relevant question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870396/access-views-in-android-actionbar

Comment: Thanks, that's a worry. It seems odd that all throughout android there is a theme of you can access what you need, but in the `ActionBar` there is a lot of this functionality excluded. I want it centred, but I don't want to have to worry about all the elements of making custom views (seems ridiculous just for centred text). I'll leave this open and see if anyone has a clever solution / workaround

Comment: No solution as of yet. It seems the only options are to either deal with it as it is, or create your own custom view layout that looks like the default, and has correctly aligned text, then set it for the `ActionBar.Tab` with `ActionBar.Tab.setCustomView()`. Considering the effort behind completely recreating the layout with the correct layout options, seems easier just to keep them to one line ;) Another option could be to find in the source where the default tab view layout is constructed and copy that in as a custom view

Comment: I put a comment on the question just noting that, this answer was accepted as it seems to be the only possible solution

Answer (score 0):

please download the follwing example. it will help you. i am sure i take help from this demo.
https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock

Comment: Which example are you talking to? ABS is an entire project to allow use of the `ActionBar` on earlier Android versions